# Programatically backing up (and emailing) a full MySQL database via PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, backup

I need to take a backup of a MySQL database daily, and preferably have it email itself to an email address of my choosing.

Is it possible to do this? What is the SQL to generate a backup file? How can I add this file as an "attachment" to the email which is sent?

Thanks for the help, I really need to make these backups!

I do know how to call a script via cronjob, so the daily thing is not a problem.

Comment: Don't forget you'll want to GZIP it too, preferably as an encrypted ZIP with a password.

Comment: As a courtesy to the recipient and the admins of the mail servers, you should consider storing the file somewhere (FTP, etc) and emailing a link instead of the full file.  One place I've worked was crippled one day when someone did exactly what you're proposing with a massive backup file.

Comment: I know how to gzip, I cna do that. As far as linking, that might not work since this is to prevent loss of data in the event of an outage

Comment: sending an email is not sufficient to prove you have a backup.  You should consider enhancing your process to include steps that close the loop, verifying that the backup is safely received and restorable.  If you do that then pulling from a link makes sense, as its less work to retry or rerun compared to sending the 'massive payload' email.

Comment: What do you mean? Its emailing a database which is currently 1 MB uncompressed to a single email address, I have a gmail account set up to receive my backups. I might only have it send once a week, as most data will remain the same throughout with only a few changes.

Answer (score 10):

Simply drop to a command shell and run a mysql_dump command like so:

```
mysqldump <DB name> -u<user> -p<password> | gzip -c > /backup/`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql.gz
```

From this point you can just use the mail command (I don't know the syntax off hand to attach a file).

Comment: Arg, I ran out of votes today, but very nice answer. Give me 7 hours, I will return to +1

Comment: I also use this approach in a crontab at my web host.  In addition, I also tar/gzip the associated web app files.

Comment: Yeah, you can run that through PHP's `exec` function

Comment: Can you give an example of the syntax used for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`exec`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to call *mysqldump* in the command-line to create a backup of your database to a file of your choosing.

```
 mysqldump -u username -p password databaseName > databaseFile.sql
```

Then in PHP, you can locate the file and upload as an attachment and send it out.

I do not know how safe sending the database is via e-mail, if there is alternative solutions I could suggest, I would.

Per Tom's comment, take a look at [**PHP Zlib**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) and [**creating GZIP files "on the fly"**](http://forums.devarticles.com/general-programming-help-4/creating-gzip-fileson-the-fly-2294.html) to zip files through PHP.

Comment: You probably want to tar/gzip it as well unless it's trivially small.

Answer (score 3):

Automatic MySql Backup Script

This script finds all of the MySQL databases on your server, individually backs them up, compresses them, and stores the file in a specified directory and/or emails it to you. It has been updated since the initial public release and includes several new features.

http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/automatic-mysql-backup-script/

Comment: Is there any way to just make it back up a single database?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use

MySQL database backup
    =====================
    http://restkultur.ch/personal/wolf/scripts/db_backup

However it's a bit old, and I'm not sure if they upgraded the version etc. But it works well, and givse you lot of backup options (how many days to keep, months, as well as where to store the file - it can be uploaded via FTP to another server for redundant security).

Comment: I don't have that kind of access unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean control? In case I mislead you with talks of FTp etc...This is as simple as installing wordpress, really. Upload it, configure the mysql access username password, select db, select frequencies and you're done. By default the .sql files are stored within the application folder. Or should i say "directory" instead of "folder" since we're talking about apache servers? :P

Comment: No, the problem is being able to access /backups/, my website is stored in /home/<myuser>/

Comment: no it lays within eaach account... so if you have /backups/ set from your FTP, it'd be under /home/<myuser>/backups

In my case, I have it under my admin module - which is at /home/jeffkee/admin/db_backup/

The folder name/location doesn't matter as long as you set it up right.